# Create a backup domain controller, but don't want it to do anything

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller

I set up a second domaincontroller fot backup, but if I take a look at he log files, I see that is manages logons for half of my computers, etc...

Can I set it up that it actually does nothing, except replication of the primary DC?

Thanks.

Comment: There hasn't been a backup or primary DC in over 15 years, and furthermore, why do you care if it services user logins or not?

Comment: `I set up a second domain controller for backup` - You're doing it wrong.

Comment: Questions must demonstrate a **minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Try including attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See [How can I ask better questions on Server Fault?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/3608/118258) for further guidance.

Answer (score 5):

> I set up a second domaincontroller fot backup,

No, you did not. You did set up a second domain controller. Your intention is irrelevant here. If you want a backup, make a backup.

> I see that is manages logons for half of my computers,

As it should.

> Can I set it up that it actually does nothing,

No. You can not. That is not supported - and generally also quite senseless. You now have 2 DC - be happy that it actually works well. More uptime than a simple backup. And for a backup, make a backup.